# Accidentaly Removed Windows From Grub

Tags: grub2

I was messing around with grub settings (only renaming entries, nothing else) and it appears that windows is no longer on the grub menu. I seem to remember it is in /something/SDA. My system is dualbooted with win xp and lubuntu. How should I add windows back to the grub menu? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome Callum B to AskUbuntu,
first i want to give you two advices regarding Ubuntu (and eventually every piece of sofware):

1- keep always a backup of the files/settings that you are going to modify

2- try to search for answers already made in the topic, that will give you a more mature answer to use

for this case
try running `sudo update-grub` this way you will restore the windows menu entry
then backup the file and try renaming again

Answer (score 0):

boot into lubuntu and install [BootRepair software](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and rebuild grub